# Polarizing filter for TLR camera (Flexaret VII)

Tags: film, filters, polarizer

I recently purchased a Flexaret VII camera and now looking for polarizing filters. I could find color filters but not polarizing. Is there any alternative on the market, as I can't find any information on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera uses B36 bayonet mount filters which are increasingly rare. I believe they are also called “Bayonet II”, or “Bay II”

There is a B36 PL filter available on eBay right now that I think would work for you  [BAY II Bay 2 Polarizer FILTER | B36](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ROLLEIFLEX-BAY-II-Bay-2-Polarizer-FILTER-B36-for-ROLLEI-3-5F-TLR-39/323526267871?hash=item4b53ab13df:g:~8QAAOSwG9Fb2MiL)

[image]

[This](http://www.jla-analog.net/tag/filter-adapter/) person had a similar problem and the solution was to have a B36 filter adapter custom made. It happens to be for 62mm filters.

A 62mm filter would slightly obscure your viewing lens but you could have a smaller size made as well.

[image]
[image]

The best solution might be a ready made Bay II adapter: [Camera-Depot](http://www.camera-depot.com/TLR.htm)
[image]

Ideally you could have one adapter for each lens but I think 49mm might be too large. There might be smaller sizes available some where as well.

Comment: Interesting about the B36–62mm adapter. But wouldn't the "step-up" obscure the TLR's viewing lens?

Comment: thanks a lot mate, I was not hoping for an answer on this topic

Comment: "that person" is active on this forum as well :) the Flexaret bay is proprietary. I have never seen a real Flexaret polarizer - only listed in sales materials. I suspect they were made in very, very low numbers from materials imported from the West (we are talking deep socialism, with serious shortages of just about everything). At present a step down adapter is the only option. 62mm is huge, but it doesn't obstruct view. 49mm is more common, as 49mm was standard filter size for Prakticas and there are tons of 49mm filters around in Czech.